# Error: ETIMEDOUT while invoking a promise that works when called alone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, es6-promise

The problem I'm facing is this: On the backend of my app I take an object submitted by third parties service and I store it on Mongo.
While doing this operation if the object doesn't have an 'image' attribute I want to fetch its url 'og-image' metadata value(through ''metaget'' ).
Since the operation of retrieveing data could be less or more time consuming I decided to write a promise that looks like that:

```
function getmetaImage(link){
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        metaget.fetch(link,function(err, meta){
            if (err){console.log(err)}
            else{                
                res(meta["og:image"]);
            }

    })

    })
}
```

So in the Mongo connection part I check the attribute and if it lacks the image I call: `getmetaImage(link).then(function(response){ /* Here I query the database with an upsert containing the response value for the image field */}`
The problem is that when I call the function alone it works but when I start the database operation I get the following error:

> { Error: ETIMEDOUT >at Timeout._onTimeout 
>   (/home/alessandro/ri/node_modules/request/request.js:846:19) >at >ontimeout (timers.js:469:11) >at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5) >at >Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', connect: true }

What do you think am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: If you get an error, your code never resolves or rejects your promise so it will just stay in the pending state forever.

Comment: yes, and I really can't figure out if the problem is in the code or it is a setting (something like that) of Mongo..

Comment: You aren't understanding my comment.  Inside of your `if (err)` you need to do `rej(err)`.

Comment: You are right , I dindn't understand the comment. Thanks

Comment: I added the rejection code and a ".catch" to the function invocation too. I still get the error. I'm starting to think that it is caused by the database because unable to handle the the rate of the requests...